# Error: unexpected ',' in "ggplot(dat in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am simply trying to read in a CSV file using R and create a scatterplot using ggplot. I have done this before with no problems when using different files, but this current one is giving me problems

All I'm doing is entering the commands below:

```
dat<-read.csv("IV.csv")
head(dat)
     a        b
1 -80.2502 -1.24274
2 -80.2034 -1.27208
3 -80.1567 -1.06815
4 -80.1100 -1.33416
5 -80.0165 -1.67727
6 -79.9698 -1.32458

ggplot(dat, aes=(x=a,y=b)) + geom_point(shape=1)
Error: unexpected ',' in "ggplot(dat, aes=(x=a,"
```

What is going on?

Comment: Try it without the `=` immediately following `aes`.

Comment: That's it. aes() not aes=()

Comment: thanks, how silly of me

Answer (score 9):

you have a syntax error:

remove the `=` sign after `aes`

from

```
ggplot(dat, aes=(x=a,y=b)) + geom_point(shape=1)
```

to

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=a,y=b)) + geom_point(shape=1)
```

Comment: Already answered in comments.